# Choosing a strong/flexible wire for Piezo bender

Tags: soldering, wire, piezo

I am using [AB4113B](https://puiaudio.com/product/benders/AB4113B)

The issue: Due to vibrations wire soldered on the Piezo is breaking.

The setup: Piezo (metal end) soldered on a PCB directly, and wire is soldered on ceramic part to a PCB pad close by.

Wires used so far: 28AWG tinned cooper multi-strand wire, here is the [link](https://robu.in/product/high-quality-ultra-flexible-28awg-silicone-wire-5-m-green/)

Doubts:

1. What would be a better wire for more flexibility?
2. What kind of glue should be used to relieve solder joint strain and add strength?
3. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Where is the break occurring? Is the solder breaking off from the piezo? Or is the wire breaking after at the solder joint? If it is the wire, McMaster-Carr sells "continuous-flex wire" which are meant for robotics applications, https://www.mcmaster.com/products/wire/electrical-wire~/continuous-flex-wire/

Comment: Thanks for sharing these wires, wire is breaking after the solder joint while ceramic part stays intact. I am looking into these "continuous-flex wire", would it be better to use 32 AWG PTFE wires, they are rated for MIL specs.

Comment: When using continuous-flex wire, we typically use the thinnest wire that can still carry the current. What you want is flexibility. Solder likes to flow up the wire, which stiffens it. You want to pour glue over this stiffened portion.

Comment: Thanks @C.Dunn, we are definitely looking for some silicone based glue to add strength over this stiffened region.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [document from PUI the manufacturer](https://puiaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Howdoyousolderwiresontopiezobenders1.pdf) on the correct method of soldering to their piezo bender parts. They recommend using 28 to 32 AWG stranded wire. No mention of using strain relief glue, though the picture does seem to show either a covering or some excess flux around the joint.

Here is yet [another detailed instruction](https://blog.piezo.com/how-to-safely-solder-joints-onto-piezo-transducers) for soldering of two different types of piezo elements.

Another way to solve this issue may be to emulate what [this vendor](https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/smart-interface) is offering. This vendor makes custom flat flex cables for attaching to piezo elements (as pictured below). If your application is of any volume you might want to look into having something like this designed. The cables from this vendor do include strain relief with flanges for mounting holes a short distance from the element edge. You may be able to create something similar to this by using standard 2-pin flex cable. You could select the pin to pin pitch of the cable so that it matches up with the desired contact points on your piezo device. If you use a polyimide cable material (as the pictured parts seem to be) that should provide an extra degree of resistance to damage from vibration and other mechanical stress.

[image]
Above picture is from [Piceramic.com](https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/smart-interface).

Comment: Thanks  for the response and all the links, I have gone through them already.
Although, These flex cables look interesting, I would be looking into this.

Comment: @Anurag - Here is yet another link to what seems to be the same part:  https://supersqlar.life/product_details/36786112.html